# Generic method to apply operation on the given struct member

Tags: c++, templates, generics, struct

I want to implement a generic method that could apply a determined operation on a struct member, passing that member as parameter. Something like this:

```
typedef struct Type_t{
    int a;
    double b;
} Type;

void gen_method(Type &t, TypeMember m){
    t.m += 1;
}
```

## What I've done until now:

```
typedef struct Type_t{
    int a;
    double b;
} Type;

typedef double Type::* PointerToTypeMemberDouble;

void gen_method(Type &t, PointerToTypeMemberDouble member){
    t.*member += 1;
}
```

## What I want to do

Now I want to implement the same generic method but using templates to allow the user to access any struct member, independentrly of its type. This is what I've tested:

```
typedef struct Type_t{
    int a;
    double b;
} Type;

template<typename T>
struct PointerToTypeMember{
    typedef T Type::* type;
};

template<typename T>
void gen_method(Type &t, PointerToTypeMember<T>::type member){
    // ...
}
```

## The error

When I try to compile, I get this errors list:
`error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'type'`

And this warning:
`warning C4346: 'myNamesPace::Type<T>::type' : dependent name is not a type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, for your error, you need to specify `typename`:

```
template<typename T>
void gen_method(Type &t, typename PointerToTypeMember<T>::type member) {
```

See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Secondly, you don't need the helper class template `PointerToTypeMember` at all. And because [nested-name-specifier couldn't be deduced in template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), you have to specify the template argument when use it as:

```
Type t{};
gen_method<int>(t, &Type::a);
gen_method<double>(t, &Type::b);
```

You could specify the class member as the template parameter directly,

```
template<typename T>
void gen_method(Type &t, T Type::*member){
    t.*member += 1;
}
```

and no need to specify the template argument, template argument deduction will do it for you.

```
Type t{};
gen_method(t, &Type::a);
gen_method(t, &Type::b);
```

Comment: Note that your sample allows to deduce member type whereas OP has to specify the member type in `gen_method` call.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

```
template<typename T>
void gen_method(Type &t, typename PointerToTypeMember<T>::type member){
    // ...
}
```

The problem was that I have to tell the compiler that `PointerToTypeMember<T>::type` is a type using the `typename` keyword.